# How to create a totally black material?

Tags: node-editor

I am trying to create something that is TOTALLY black. I don't mean something like diffuse, or glossy, where things will reflect off it and lights will light it up.

I mean something that is totally black.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: imho, in theory, you can't see any detail of a "totally black" object. Is this what you wish, a rendered black hole?

Comment: You could possibly use an emission shader set to black and strength 0, or you could try a holdout shader and then alpha over composite it onto a solid black image.

Comment: What renderer do you want to use? In Blender Render, you can try to enable Shading -> Shadeless in the material option, if you use Cycles, you can try this material setup:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21535/13643

Comment: Well that is what a totally black diffuse shader will do in Cycles, in theory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding you. In cycles this is just a black diffuse shader.

This picture the sun is set to 1.
[image]

This picture the sun is set to 1000.

[image]

The material doesn't reflect or anything if you don't add fresnel or gloss to it.

Comment: Oh right, thankyou :) I tried that originally, and it didn't seem to work. I don't know what i did, but it wasn't diffuse, so I tried it again and it worked :D. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Greetings from the future (10/31/2019). I do not know if this has always been the case, but simply creating any kind of material and deleting every node but the "Material Output Node" will have the same effect as a pure black material that ignores all light interaction. I tested this in Blender 2.80.