# Where Is Shadeless Material Option For Blender 2.8?

Tags: materials

just trying to use shadeless lighting for a material, but cant find where it is in 2.8
This is how it looked in the older versions:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just plug some color/texture directly to the Material Output surface input.

Answer (score 9):

The option shown there is for Blender Internal renderer, which has been removed in Blender 2.8. See the following questions for information on how to create a shadeless material using the shader node graph.

[Totally white shadeless material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21533/totally-white-shadeless-material-in-cycles)

[Node for setting render colour, regardless of lighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8108/node-for-setting-render-colour-regardless-of-lighting)

These setups will work for both Cycles and EEVEE in Blender 2.8

Comment: Hi. This is currently a link-only answer. If the other questions disappear, then this answer no longer provides information. Please include at least *some* of the actual techniques mentioned in those answers in the body of your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For those wanting to turn off shading in a script in python, the old:

```
bpy.context.object.active_material.use_shadeless = True
```

is now in Blender 2.8x:

```
bpy.context.object.active_material.shadow_method = 'NONE'
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You have that option while importing the plane. Press  <kbd>N</kbd> to make the options visible or use the gear icon on the top right of the window

Change the Material from Principled to Shadeless.

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 3+, if you just plug the Color straight to your material output Surface, you get unshaded data.

Comment: Seems to work. I plugged a color ramp node's output to the surface input of the Material output node.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the surface to "Emission", and strength to 1, seems to work.

[image]

Comment: bad idea, because then it emits light.

Comment: It doesn't work when the image has some transparent alpha parts, those are set to black.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to mess with nodes or read over multiple FAQ.

What you're looking for is the, "Flat" Lighting Method in the "Solid" Viewport Shading options.

In the image below I have the 'Color Type' set to 'Texture' to preview my Baked out AO without any additional Shading or Lighting.

[image: Flat Viewport Shading (Shadeless)]

To render wwitch to **Workbench** render engine.

Comment: This only affects the viewport and isn't comparable to the blender render "shadeless" material option.

Comment: @bstnhnsl No - you can render it with Workbench engine , and yes - it is not comparable  with 2.79, but in a meaning of possibilities combine other materials.

Comment: I love this technics but it is really hard to work with it with photogrammetry asset as you can't model on top of it, every other mesh will also be flat, making it worthless.

Answer (score 1):

*Import Image As Plane* Addons seems to show the right way using nodes:

[image]

Simply use a `Mix Shader` with `IAP_SHADELESS`

Comment: This seems to work better than the other options, but keep in mind IAP_SHADELESS is only added when you use this add on