# Giving smoke no shadow

Tags: rendering, shaders, smoke-simulation, shadows

I've been trying to use smoke as a way to show simple steam for some hot coffee, generally looks good except the steam has a huge shadow, not something I really see in real life, so I'm trying to disable it's shadow. I've read these posts:

[Totally white shadeless material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21533/totally-white-shadeless-material-in-cycles)

[Where Is Shadeless Material Option For Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131015/where-is-shadeless-material-option-for-blender-2-8)

Which generally suggest this node setup (what I'm currently using):

[image]

But my final render still has a shadow (notice the black shadow off to the right of the coffee cup):

[image]

I've applied this node setup on the "smoke" material generated when I add "quick smoke" --  not to the smoke domain, doing that results in a big white box, which makes sense. I don't really know where else I can setup this shader so I'm assuming I'm doing it right, but maybe not, a little unclear to me.

Any help greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Cycles:

Select your smoke object, go to *Object Properties* tab, then *Visibility > Ray Visibility* and disable *Shadows*.

[image]