# Is it possile to create a flat-color (shadeless) shader in Blender 2.83 that is also flat when in a reflection?

Tags: materials, shaders

Toon BSDF and Shader to RGB not fit for me, and I trying to create flat color shader in cycles. I decided to use this shader, and it works well, until the metallic roughness not "0", then it is reflect like diffuse. I was looking for it on other questions, but there shaders not completely flat. And I want just shadeless material, and this should be reflect like flat. This s blender file, if you want to test shader quickly

Edited:
Diffuse shader added to not to illuminate objects around

Edited 2:
Partially resolved with adding "Is Glossy ray" output to "Fac", but some part of rays still illumnate objects around. Not final resolve

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). The Emmision shader with strength=1 will give you exactly that. A flat color not receiving any shadows or lights.

Comment: @JachymMichal So am I doing this, or what do you mean? This shader does not work in reflection, when roughness chahging

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131015/where-is-shadeless-material-option-for-blender-2-8   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148336/blender-2-8-shadeless-material-setup-not-shadeless

Comment: @batFINGER I readed this erlier, it is not working

Answer (score 7):

**Flat Color**

- plug *RGB* node directly, there is no need to use *Emission* shader

**Flat Color in Reflection with Roughness**

- math *Light Path* of *Camera Ray* with *Glossy Ray*** and use as factor in *Mix Shader* node

**Shadow**

- current setup generates shadow, if you dont want that plug *Transparent* shader into top *Shader* socket of *Mix Shader* node.

For your Edit2: **Delete your Diffuse Shader** that generates indirect light on surrounding objects.

[image]
[image]

Great article to check [How the light path node works](https://artisticrender.com/how-the-light-path-node-works-in-blender/)