# Create an image without using lighting?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I am not using Blender to render a scene with lighting.  I am using it to create a 3D model for a project.

To start, I want to create a white box with a black outline and numbers in the corners.  I did that in the environment.  Here is a pic:
[image]

Now, I want to create an image of it as a PNG file.  When I go to render the image, I get a page with a lot of gray color to it:
[image]

I would really like just a black and white picture with no lighting effects, just perspective.

Is that possible?

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148336/blender-2-8-shadeless-material-setup-not-shadeless

Comment: You can set the World's color to white (it's gray by default, that's why your pics are gray). And you can also use Emission shader, so the lights won't affect the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Render Properties* > *Color Management* (scroll down to the bottom) and change the *View Transform* from "Filmic" (default) to "Standard" - this will make your white's white.

[image: Transform]

Comment: That is what I needed, thank you!